# Verificar Existência de Conexão com MySQL no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, conexão

Me surgiu esta dúvida recentemente, como verificar se existe uma conexão aberta com o mysql?
Todos sabem que para se utilizar o `mysql_real_escape_string` precisa ter uma conexão certo, então eu queria verificar se existe uma, se sim ai usar `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Pergunta um pouco estranho, porque, isso pelo seu código você consegue saber se tem conexão ou não, uma coisa também e um dica parem de usar mysql_connect, esse código está depreciado nas novas versões do seu PHP, então, utilize PDO (http://us1.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) ou Mysqli (http://us1.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

Nesse link tem como pegar o erro simplesmente por mysql_error (http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php), o primeiro exemplo pode te ajudar !!!

Comment: [pq não utilizar as funções mysql_*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-nao-devemos-usar-funcoes-do-tipo-mysql)

Answer (score 7):

Podes verificar assim:

```
<?php
if(is_resource($connection) && get_resource_type($connection) === 'mysql link')
{
    //esta conectado.
}
else
{
    //não está conectado
}
?>
```

ou simplesmente esta que retorna falso se não houver conexão:

```
mysql_thread_id($connection)
```

Fonte: [SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075116/php-how-to-determine-if-a-database-connection-is-open)

Answer (score 7):

A função mysql_ping retorna FALSE se não houver conexão, com a vantagem de tentar reconectar antes, caso a conexão tenha sido perdida em um script:

```
mysql_ping ([ $identificador_da_conexao ] )
```

Veja o manual:

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-ping.php

> Importante: as funções `mysql_` não existem a partir do PHP 5.5. Aprenda a usar as funções `mysqli_`, que são mais seguras e completas. [Clique aqui e veja a **documentação**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Aí vem a pergunta: Antes de mais nada, você está abrindo a conexão no seu código?

Comment: E tem outra coisa interessante: Esta resposta é tecnicamente correta pro que foi perguntado, mas a pergunta e a resposta ja são tão obsoletas quanto as funções em questão.

Comment: Só pontuando a versão do PHP. Na versão 5.5 ela se tornou obsoleta mas continuava funcionando. Ela foi removida na versão 7.0.0. 
Em sua documentação diz:
"Esta extensão está obsoleta desde o PHP 5.5.0 e foi removida no PHP 7.0.0."
Fonte: [link](http://br1.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-ping.php)

Comment: @ChristianoRibeiroSoares é uma observação válida, mas espero que tenha notado que a pergunta e os comentários são de 2014 :D - de qq forma, preciso dar umas repassadas em respostas antigas pra atualizar. - grato pelo lembrete

Answer (score 2):

Obrigado Jorge B.! A solução que melhor funciona é:

```
<?php


if(is_resource($connection) && get_resource_type($connection) === 'mysql link'){

//esta conectado.

} else {

//não está conectado

}


?>
```

Porque usando o `mysql_ping()` ou o `mysql_thread_id()`, quando a conexão está encerrada, esses comandos retornam erro, pois não existe *resource* para eles trabalharem...

Comment: Marque a resposta do Jorge como a correta, assim já sinaliza para os outros usuários. Não repita a resposta.